# Принудительная авторизация samba в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Проблема в том, что если имеется возможность войти в качестве гостя, то nautulus не даёт возможности совершить авторизацию под нужным пользователем. Подскажите как это можно исправить.